# Efficient way to group database rows by column?

Tags: python, algorithm, postgresql

Let's say I'm building a dating app that generates recommendations for users based on their dating goals. Let's say the users are represented in the database like so:

```
       Column        |            Type                                     
---------------------+-----------------------------
 id                  | bigint
 updated_since       | timestamp
 goal                | text
```

And let's say the value for `goal` can be one of four things:

1. `seeking_sugar_daddy`
2. `seeking_sugar_mama`
3. `be_sugar_daddy`
4. `be_sugar_mama`

Now, let's say I have a recommendation engine that runs periodically and generates matches for all users based on goals and some other criteria (height, age, etc). The recommendation engine takes a pair of users as an input and generates a score.

What's the most efficient way to generate a list of inputs to the recommendation engine? The only valid inputs are pairs that have matching goals - for example, if `User A` has a goal `seeking_sugar_daddy`, and `User B` has a goal `be_sugar_daddy` that would be a valid input, but `seeking_sugar_daddy` and `be_sugar_mama` would not be a valid pair.

Once I grab all the users from the database, how should I group them? Or is there a way to do this in the database?

Comment: `dating app`? man of african descendence please..

Comment: ha - not actually building a dating app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's abbreviate your goals to `"A"`, `"C"`, `"G"`, `"T"`, where A matches T and C matches G.  Here are your matches:

```
SELECT * from users AS a JOIN users AS b 
ON (a.goal = "A" AND b.goal = "T") OR (a.goal = "C" and b.goal = "G")
```

Note that since the same table appears on the left and right, there's no need to check for `a.goal = "T"` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I ended up going with something similar:

    `SELECT u1.id, array_agg(u2.id)
    FROM user AS u1
    JOIN user as u2 
    ON (u1.goal = 'A' and u2.goal = 'T') 
    OR (u2.goal = 'C' and u2.goal = 'G')
    GROUP BY u1.id;`

Answer (score 1):

You need a `relationship` table to pair attributes. *(of course you use ids no text)*

```
  atributeA             |  atributeB
  --------------------------------------------
  seeking_sugar_daddy   |  be_sugar_daddy
  be_sugar_daddy        |  seeking_sugar_daddy
  ....
```

Then you match user like this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM users u1
 JOIN relationship r
   ON u1.goal = r.atributeA
 JOIN users u2
   ON r.attributeB = u2.goal
```

**NOTE:** This allow you to add more attributes later instead of hard code the conditions on the query.

Also I duplicate/invert the relationship to make search like `who are the match for 'UserA'` easier.  But if you just want all the user matchs, don't need the duplicated.

Comment: Nice idea, but when you put all pairs (reverse included) into this `relationship` table, then the query's result will also include every matching user-pair twice (once reversed). I don't know if that's what OP wants though.